# Need to apply a loader to all dependencies of a certain file recursively

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am building a universal JavaScript application that relies on a single config file. The config contains mostly code that can be safely executed on the server and within the browser, but certain files and functions should be run server-side only.

I have built a Babel plugin that I use along with `babel-loader` and I apply this loader to the config file itself *as well as* any file that is required directly from the config using the `issuer` Webpack rule:

*Relevant Webpack loaders:*

```js
        {
          test: paths.config,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  [removeObjectProperties],
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          issuer: paths.config,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  [removeObjectProperties],
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
```

*removeObjectProperties Plugin*:

```js
function removeObjectProperties() {
  return {
    visitor: {
      ObjectProperty: function ObjectProperty(path) {
        if (['access', 'hooks'].indexOf(path.node.key.name) > -1) {
          // Found a match - remove it
          path.remove();
        }
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Using the above Webpack configuration, my `removeObjectProperties` plugin successfully removes all server-only properties from both the top-level config and any modules that are require'd directly from it.

The problem is that the `issuer` Webpack rule does not apply recursively. So, if I have a file that is required from a file that is required by the config, the loader is not applied.

I could use some guidance as to how to either better achieve my goals of recursively removing certain object properties through any unknown number of required modules, or determine some other way altogether of separating out server-side only code from code that will be bundled and served to browsers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try adding the directory of the 'required' file in the include key https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleinclude using this syntax: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition

Comment: Hi @ColdFridge - thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately the app allows the user to place their config files anywhere they want - including above the directory that contains their base script. So I don't think this will work. Also, the approach you've mentioned may cause some unwanted side-effects like running the loader on files that are completely separate from my app's config files.